# MaterialBetterSpinner crashed on click

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-spinner

I am using `com.weiwangcn.betterspinner`, but instead of declare it in XML file, I create it programmatically. Below is my code, short and simple.

```
final MaterialBetterSpinner spinnerSoftener = new MaterialBetterSpinner(getActivity());
spinnerSoftener.setId((View.generateViewId()));
spinnerSoftener.setHint("Softener");
spinnerSoftener.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

List<Mill_Softener_Type> softenerList = presenter.getSoftener();
if(softenerList.size() == 0)
{
    spinnerSoftener.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, new ArrayList<>()));
    spinnerSoftener.setEnabled(false);
}
else
{
    System.out.println("softener size: " + softenerList.size());
    spinnerSoftener.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, softenerList));
    spinnerSoftener.setEnabled(true);
}
container.addView(spinnerSoftener);
```

The problem is when I click on the spinner, it will throw a `NullPointerException`. Below is the error code:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:337)
at android.widget.AdapterView.checkFocus(AdapterView.java:732)
at android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onInvalidated(AdapterView.java:855)
at android.widget.AbsListView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onInvalidated(AbsListView.java:6187)
at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyInvalidated(DataSetObservable.java:50)
at android.widget.BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated(BaseAdapter.java:59)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter$ArrayFilter.publishResults(ArrayAdapter.java:546)
at android.widget.Filter$ResultsHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:282)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

`softenerList` isn't null, I can print out its size from `else` part. I don't know what is the problem, any idea?

Comment: What is `presenter` here?

Comment: If it wasn't null, you wouldn't get that error

Comment: @AndiGeeky my presenter class, return a list of softener.

Comment: @cricket_007 it wasn't null, I can print its size. and from the error message, non of the classes are from my class, so I don't know where does it occur.

Comment: `ArrayAdapter.getCount` is called by default when you create a `new ArrayAdapter`. If the list you pass is null, then `size()` is called on a null list. Are you filtering anything on that adapter? `Filter$ResultsHandler` is something that seems you are.

Comment: @cricket_007 I did nothing other than the code I show here. Thats all the code about the `MaterialBetterSpinner `

Comment: Okay, so the question I have is: When does the crash occur? Always? Only when you click on the spinner?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes, always. It occurs every time when I click on the spinner.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Mill_Softener_Type> softenerList = new ArrayList<>();

 softenerList = presenter.getSoftener();
```

Comment: Wrong. If `presenter.getSoftener()` returns null, again the list is null

Comment: While this code may (or may not) answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.

Answer (score 0):

here presenter.getSoftener(); return null values, so you have to check first if it is giving null values reference.

```
List<Mill_Softener_Type> softenerList = presenter.getSoftener();

if (softenerList != null){
  if(softenerList.size() == 0) {
    // your code
  } else {
    // your code
  }
  container.addView(spinnerSoftener);
}
```

Comment: no it doesn't return null, as I can print out the size of it in `else` part.

Comment: how you print out size? what is the size your are getting for this?

Comment: `System.out.println("softener size: " + softenerList.size());`, and the size is 1 as there is only one softener so far

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I don't see why you can't use XML here, but the list is not null, since you say you can print the size and the stacktrace says otherwise.

Regardless, I would re-write that without the `new ArrayList<>` because if you have an empty list, you'll have an empty adapter. No need to treat it any differently.

```
final Context context = getActivity();
final MaterialBetterSpinner spinnerSoftener = new MaterialBetterSpinner(context);
spinnerSoftener.setId((View.generateViewId()));
spinnerSoftener.setHint("Softener");
spinnerSoftener.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

List<Mill_Softener_Type> softenerList = presenter.getSoftener();
if(softenerList != null)
{
    int size = softenerList.size();
    System.out.println("softener size: " + size);
    spinnerSoftener.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, softenerList));
    spinnerSoftener.setEnabled(size > 0);
}
container.addView(spinnerSoftener);
```

And if you still get exceptions, then they are likely caused elsewhere in the code, whether that is in yours or in the library you are using.